# Solidity get return variable from a send method in React

Tags: solidity, react

I'm trying to call a method that pushes data to my Blockchain and then returns back the ID of the new struct I created. This is how I'm calling the method in my React code:

```
const documentId = await storehash.methods.sendDocument(this.state.IPFSlink, newDate).send({from: this.state.account}).call()
```

And here is my smart contract method:

```
function sendDocument(
    string memory _ipfsLocation, 
    uint256 _uploadDate 
) 
public 
returns (uint256)
{
    documentCount ++;
    ListOfDocuments[documentCount] = documentStore(documentCount, _ipfsLocation, msg.sender, _uploadDate);
    return documentCount ;
}
```

So it *should* created the new struct and return back the ID. However, it causes the following error:

> Unhandled Rejection (Error): invalid tuple value (coderType="tuple", value="QmStXLfxUJuc4xTtSGQxmF1PXrjVmsosqL6Wyi5EuQiYNH", version=4.0.26)

Can anyone help me understand what I'm doing wrong?

p.s sorry if I've formatted this badly, it's my first time using a stackexchange.

Comment: Don't think you can do `send(...).call()`. You should `await` for `send(...)` to complete, and then `call` the `view` function which returns the data that you need.

Comment: @goodvibration Sorry, I'm a bit new to this, can you elaborate what you mean by view function?

Comment: A function which doesn't change the state of the blockchain, i.e., doesn't change any of the state-variables of the contract it belongs to, and doesn't call any other function (in this contract or in another) which does. When a non-view function is called **from the off-chain**, it returns (to the off-chain caller) the transaction hash, not the value in the return statement.

Comment: So would I be able to have 1 method which creates the new struct and returns the id to me or is this impossible in 1 method? Thank you for your help by the way.